# Galaxy rotation equation problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, astronomy, newtonian-gravity

I would like to know if in this equation for the rotation of galaxies: 
$$v^2=\frac{GM}r.$$
Is $M$ the mass of the black hole at the center of our galaxy?

Someone said to me that

> No, $M$ is the mass of all matter that is enclosed in the spherical shell of radius $r$.This includes the mass of the black-hole,mass of the galactic disk up to radius $r$ and also the mass in the halo.

However, the quantity $GMm/r^2$ indicates the opposite because we derived $v^2=GM/r$ by equating $v^2 m/r=GMm/r^2$, where $M$ is the mass of the object at the centre (e.g. the Sun in our solar system) and the velocity is a function of the distance. What is the mass of that black hole?

Comment: Ignoring the obvious lack of relativistic treatment, the $M$ is the total mass contained in shell of radius $r$.

Comment: Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem

Comment: @ja72: why would someone treat this relativistically?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Since a galaxy is several thousand light years across and it takes millions of lights years to revolve, it might need relativistic treatment. Isn't the $c\, {\rm d}t$ component of distance significant compared to ${\rm d}x$ in $ds=\sqrt{(dx)^2+\ldots-(c dt)^2}$.

Comment: @ja72: that's not the right way of looking at it--the speeds involved are small (relativistically, at least), and the gravitational fields (at least far enough out in the galaxy where we're worrying about the galactic rotation curves), the gravitational dynamics are extremely Newtonian, unless you believe in MOND.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use the concept of gravitational field to derive this one.  We can think of the field $\vec g$ as just being the acceleration due to gravity at a point${}^{1}$.

Now, let's assuem that $\vec g$ everywhere points radially inward (i.e., we have a spherically symmetric charge distribution).    Then, to find the velocity of orbit, we have:

$$\begin{align}
F &= ma\\
mg &= m\frac{v^{2}}{r}\\
v &= \sqrt{gr}
\end{align}$$

Now, how do we calculate the gravitational field?  It turns out that it satisfies this nifty equation:

$${\vec \nabla}\cdot {\vec g} = 4\pi G\rho$$

where $\rho$ is the density of the matter creating the charge distribution${}^{2}$.

Now, let's assume that our matter distribution is uniform.  So, $\rho$ is just some density, and we also assume that $\vec g$ only has radial components.  Then, it is easy to show that this equation just becomes:

$$ \frac{dg}{dr} =4\pi G \rho$$

Which has solution (assuming that $g(0) = 0$, which makes sense, since there are equal amounts of mass pulling us in all directions at the center of our mass distribution)

$$g= 4\pi G \rho r$$

Now, noting that the mass enclosed in a radius $r$, we can eliminate the density in favor of the mass enclosed by using the definition of density:

$$\begin{align}
M_{inc} &= \rho V\\
&= \rho(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^{3})\\
4\pi\rho r &= \frac{3M_{inc}}{r^{2}}
\end{align}$$

and we get $g = 3G\frac{M_{inc}}{r^{2}}$

Finally, back-substituting into our original equation, we find:

$$\begin{align}
v_{orbit} &= \sqrt{gr}\\
&= \sqrt{4\pi G\rho r^{2}}\\
&= r\sqrt{4\pi G \rho}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{3GM_{inc}}{r}}
\end{align}$$

Where I reintroduced the enclosed mass in the last line to answer the question, but note that the second to last line is the more interesting one--it tells us that if we plot the velocity of orbit against the distance from the center of the galaxy, we should get something approaching a straight line if we have a galaxy with uniform density.

The fact that velocities obey this law, even in regions of galaxies where there appeared to be very little visible matter, is one of the clearest pieces of evidence for dark matter in modern cosmology.

${}^{1}$ Please, please PLEASE note that $g \neq 9.8 {\rm m/s^{2}}$ in this case.  It varies depending on what the masses of the gravitating bodies are and how far you are from them.

${}^{2}$ it turns out, using some vector calculus, it can be shown that if the matter is a point charge of mass M, then you have $g = G\frac{M}{r^{2}}$, and then, since $F = mg$, we recover Newton's law $F = G\frac{mM}{r^{2}}$

Answer (score -1):

The mass is all the mass within the radius r, However this is approximate because it assumes M is a point mass. It works fine with planetary revolutions because there is such negligible mass between the Sun and the planet, and each can be assumed to be point masses.